# How can i change the focus to be on Form1 from being on the new Form?

Tags: c#

I have a button click wich i click on and it open a new Form.

Then i can click on the new Form listBox and everything.

Now when i want to back to the Form1 and click there on the menu or a button i need to click on it twice since the control/focus was on the new opened Form.

What's the best way to bring back the focus/control to Form1 without clicking on it first ?

Maybe to use an event that if i move the mouse over Form1 area it will bring the focus/control to the Form1 ?

This is how im doing to open/show the new Form:

```
if (toolStripComboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1 && toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
}
else
{
    Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Mode lightningsmode1 = new Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Mode(this);
    lightningsmode1.Show();
}
```

I want to make that even if the new Form is open without closing it im moving back to Form1 so the control/focus will be on Form1. And also if im closing/exiting the new Form so the control/focus will be on Form1 automatic without the need to click on it area first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) event to detect when the mouse is over the form. To make it gain focus, you just need to use `This.Focus()` to bring it to the front.

**EDIT**:
The code  would be in `form1`; The form you want to give focus to.

Hope this helps you!